# SaveAsTable in Spark Scala: HDP3.x

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hdp

I have one dataframe in Spark  I'm saving it in my hive as a table.But getting below error message.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException:
    com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseConnector
    does not allow create table as select.at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

can anyone please help me how should i save this  as table in hive.

```
    val df3 = df1.join(df2, df1("inv_num") === df2("inv_num")  // Join both dataframes on id column
    ).withColumn("finalSalary", when(df1("salary") < df2("salary"), df2("salary") - df1("salary")) 
    .otherwise(
    when(df1("salary") > df2("salary"), df1("salary") + df2("salary"))  // 5000+3000=8000  check
    .otherwise(df2("salary"))))    // insert from second dataframe
    .drop(df1("salary"))
    .drop(df2("salary"))
    .withColumnRenamed("finalSalary","salary")

    }
    }

    //below code is not working when I'm executing below command its throwing error as 

    java.lang.RuntimeException:
    com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseConnector
    does not allow create table as select.at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)

     df3.write.
     format("com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseConnector")
    .option("database",  "dbname")
    .option("table", "tablename")
    .mode("Append")
    .saveAsTable("tablename")
```

Note: Table is already available in database and I m using HDP 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Try `registerTempTable` and then -> `spark.sql()` -> then write

```
df3.registerTempTable("tablename");
spark.sql("SELECT salary FROM tablename")
.write.format(HIVE_WAREHOUSE_CONNECTOR)
.option("database",  "dbname")
    .option("table", "tablename")
    .mode("Append")
.option("table", "newTable")
.save()
```

Comment: Tried .save its not giving any error but I'm not getting data in my table I have checked at hdfs location and in mentiond database /tablename also.@QuickSilver

Comment: salary
 8000
 3000    I have used drop method for 'inv_num' column also so now i am getting only salary in output.@QuickSilver

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter) the behaviour of the `saveAsTable` function changes with the mode used, by default is `ErrofIfExist`.
In your case, that you are using Hive, try with `insertInto`, but keep in mind that the order of the columns of the dataframe must be the same as the destiny.

Comment: Tried but didn't work. It is working fine in cloudera  but not Working in HDP.

Answer (score 0):

See if below solution works for you,

```
val df3 = df1.join(df2, df1("inv_num") === df2("inv_num")  // Join both dataframes on id column
    ).withColumn("finalSalary", when(df1("salary") < df2("salary"), df2("salary") - df1("salary")) 
    .otherwise(
    when(df1("salary") > df2("salary"), df1("salary") + df2("salary"))  // 5000+3000=8000  check
    .otherwise(df2("salary"))))    // insert from second dataframe
    .drop(df1("salary"))
    .drop(df2("salary"))
    .withColumnRenamed("finalSalary","salary")

val hive = com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseBuilder.session(spark).build()

df3.createOrReplaceTempView("<temp-tbl-name>")
hive.setDatabase("<db-name>")
hive.createTable("<tbl-name>")
.ifNotExists()

sql("SELECT salary FROM <temp-tbl-name>")
.write
.format(HIVE_WAREHOUSE_CONNECTOR)
.mode("append")
.option("table", "<tbl-name>")
.save()
```

Comment: @QuickSilver Tried but didnt work not getting any data in table.I think when i am doing df3.registerTempTable("tablename"); its creting table in spark metadata and from there if i am writing data in hive warehouse so not getting data there.

Comment: Didn't work.For now I have saved data at hdfs loaction then loaded from there in table.